# Javascript, Firebug: How do I have multiple views or what is the right of way of doing development?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, firebug

Most of my javascript work is done with Firebug and I feel annoying most of the times having to switch between the HTML mode and console mode (which again I split into output mode and input mode). When I switch to a different page to see the HTML and come back, I lose the code that I write. What is the best way to go about developing javascript applications using firebug?

Something like a mini IDE would be awesome: It just has to let me insert some code, examine the current page and then let me execute it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a simple text editor (vim) to write Javascript and HTML, and I check the result every now and then in Firefox. I have always two windows open: one for my text editor, and one with the current page open in Firefox. After saving a change in the Javascript, I switch to the browser and refresh the page to observe results. That was my workflow until recently.

A couple of weeks ago, I discovered the Combiner tool by [Nicholas C. Zakas](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/09/22/introducing-combiner-a-javascriptcss-concatenation-tool/). To release my Javascript code, I am now using a complete build process based on [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/), similar to what I was using while doing Java development previously.

The first step is to check the Javascript code with the [JSLint tool by Douglas Crockford](http://www.jslint.com/). I used to painfully copy and paste my Javascript code in the online version of the tool, once in a while; being able to run it on all my Javascript files at once with this Ant script is a huge convenience.

The second step is to combine all my Javascript files into a single file using the Combiner tool. The third step is to minify the Javascript code using [YUI Compressor by Yahoo!](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/). These last two steps allow to optimize the delivery of Javascript code to reduce page loading.

You can find [an example Ant build file](http://bezen.org/javascript/build/build.xml) that you may adapt to your own needs. I am currently using this file to build [my own Javascript library, bezen.org](http://bezen.org/javascript/).

Answer (score 1):

The other answers so far have been correct: I've never heard of anyone actually developing inside Firefox/Firebug, because it's a tool designed for debugging, not coding.  To do your coding, you should use a tool designed for it (either a text editor or a full-fledged IDE).

But that being said, you might want to check out FireEclipse ([Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120626140258/http://www.almaden.ibm.com/u/bartonjj/fireclipse/index.html)).  It will allow you to integrate Firebug with the Eclipse IDE (which itself has at least three different JS plug-ins to choose from).  Alternatively I think the main (aka Web Standard Toolkit, aka WST) JS editor for Eclipse has some functionality which is similar to Firebug, but I've never used it so I don't know the details.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

- Write your HTML in an editor/IDE
- Save your changes
- Preview it in your browser
- Debug using Firebug
- Make your code edits in your SOURCE CODE
- Repeat

Firebug is for debugging and allows you to do some "what if" fiddling while the page is live. This is not a replacement for an IDE.

Comment: So what made me ask this question was knowing the existence of something like Selenium which actually spawns a browser instance, tests the code and then closes it. But that was mainly for code testing so I was just curious to know how the experts do this kind of a programming... :)

Comment: Yeah, I don't think FireBug us the answer for what you want. I guess you could always save the page after editing, but that just results in static HTML.